# Specify offset of ksqlDB consumer

Tags: apache-kafka, ksqldb

There is the possibility to change default offset of new consumers with

```
SET 'auto.offset.reset'='earliest';
```

I would like to know if is it possible to specify offset by timestamp like for regular kafka consumer ?

Answer (score 1):

This is currently not possible as far as I know.

You could always filter by the timestamp of the message (by default: `ROWTIME`) and apply a filter condition using `WHERE`.